# Use of tf.fill to fill with more than one element

Tags: python, tensorflow, fill, tensor

I'm trying to fill a row with different values ​​and I don't know how to do it, it just takes the last value of x

```
for i in range(len(columna1)):
    x = columna[i] * (RangoMax1-RangoMin1)+RangoMin1
    n1 = tf.fill([1,15],x)
```

The result is 
[[-1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 -1.8144 ]]

Comment: `x` here seems to be a scalar

Comment: and do you know can i change x?

Comment: are you just trying to add a new line at the bottom of a tensor? i'm not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: what I want is that the different values ​​of x put them in n1, 15 values ​​are returned to me by x and only saved the last 15 times

Comment: did you print `x` to confirm that it has multiple values?

Comment: yes i did it, and i see the different values

Comment: and why do you need the fill function? why dont you just convert to a tensor?

Comment: It's true! Thanks!!